# Are there any packages to create a group with add member system in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, usergroups

I am developing a project using Laravel 5.6 where there is requirement of group, were user can create a group, add member or send invitation to user via email and post to group and can have group chat function also.

I want to complete this module, so I am looking for Laravel packages. I have tried "teamwork" package and "groups" package.

Comment: I used [cmgmyr](https://github.com/cmgmyr/laravel-messenger) packed with some changes based on my needs :

Comment: @ako thank you that would be helpful for group messaging. I am looking for package for creating groups is there any available package you know about.

Answer (score 0):

One option in Laravel Package is https://github.com/musonza/groups
It does not have invite features. But you can create groups and manager members in the groups from the registered Users.
For invite feature you can refer to https://laravel-news.com/user-invitation-system